# Scan & Import Keywords from Word Documents into a CSV

Tags: excel, csv, ms-word

I have ALOT of Word Documents, that I would like to Scan and Import certain information such as email addresses into a CSV File, so we can use it for Email Marketing.

Are there any tools out there that can help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what platform you're on, or if the word documents are in a standard format or not, but the http://docx.codeplex.com/ library would let you open up the DOCX file and read from it.  You could find key words and pull out the text you want.